# Can we give supply and demand values in range for min cost flow problem using google or tools

Tags: or-tools

Currently its specified in documentation to provide Supply and demand in list with integer values. Is it possible to give in supply and demand in range.
Current implementation as in documentation:- 
supplies = [20, 0, 0, -5, -15]

Comment: Your question is really unclear, can you please specify  to which documentation are you referring to?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/optimization/flow/mincostflow this is the documentation link.I wanted to give supply and demand in supplies list to be in range values. Is it possible?